# Json data echarts

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, echarts

In my web application I have an echart chart and an URL that returns

```
[ { "category": "2019-01-06 21:22:56", "value1": 0.5 }, { 
"category": "2019-01-06 21:24:57", "value1": 0.5 }, { "category": 
"2019-01-08 22:09:52", "value1": 533 }, { "category": "2019-01-08 
22:10:45", "value1": -100 }, { "category": "2019-01-08 22:11:35", 
"value1": 216.5 }, { "category": "2019-01-08 22:12:25", "value1": 
-221.5 }, { "category": "2019-01-08 22:13:16", "value1": 226 } ]
```

Now I want "category" value to be shown on x-axis and "value1" value to ben shown on y-axis.

Chart code is the following:

```
var dataArr = [];
        $.get('https://myurl.com/backend/data.php', {}, 
function(response) {
            dataArr = JSON.parse(response);
            initEchart();
        });

var myChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById('main'));

function initEchart(){
            // specify chart configuration item and data
            var option = {
                title: {
                    text: 'ECharts entry example'
                },
                tooltip: {},
                legend: {
                    data:['Sales']
                },
                xAxis: {
                    data: dataArr.category 
                },
                yAxis: {},
                series: [{
                    name: 'Sales',
                    type: 'line',
                    data: dataArr.value1
                }]
            };

            // use configuration item and data specified to show 
chart
            myChart.setOption(option);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use something like this

```
function(response) {
        dataArr = JSON.parse(response);
        initEchart();
        var category = [];
        var value = [];
        for(var i = 0; i < dataArr.length; i++) {
           var item = dataArr[i];   
           category.push("\""+item[0]+"\"");
           value.push("\""+item[1]+"\"");
       }
       category= '['+category+']';
       var result_category = category.toString();

       value= '['+value+']';
       var result_value = value.toString();


      //and in chart use like this 

       xAxis: {
                data:  JSON.parse(result_category)
            },
        series: [{
                    name: 'Sales',
                    type: 'line',
                    data: JSON.parse(result_value)
                }]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dataArr[0].category
dataArr[0].value1

dataArr[1].category
dataArr[1].value1
```

This is how your array in your AJAX call, is like.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>ECharts</title>
    <!-- including ECharts file -->
    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script src="echarts.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- prepare a DOM container with width and height -->
    <div id="main" style="width: 600px;height:400px;"></div>
    <script>
    var dataArr = [];
            $.get('https://myurl.com/backend/data.php', {}, 
    function(response) {
                dataArr = JSON.parse(response);
                initEchart();
            });

    var myChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById('main'));

    function initEchart(){
                // specify chart configuration item and data
                var option = {
                    title: {
                        text: 'ECharts entry example'
                    },
                    tooltip: {},
                    legend: {
                        data:['Sales']
                    },
                    xAxis: {
                        type: 'category',
                        data: [dataArr[0].category, dataArr[1].category, dataArr[2].category, dataArr[3].category, dataArr[4].category, dataArr[5].category, dataArr[6].category]                        
                    },
                    yAxis: {},
                    series: [{
                        name: 'Sales',
                        type: 'line',
                        data: [dataArr[0].value1, dataArr[1].value1, dataArr[2].value1, dataArr[3].value1, dataArr[4].value1, dataArr[5].value1, dataArr[6].value1]                        
                    }]
                };

                myChart.setOption(option);
            }    
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```